# need to check length on exit of keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote a keyupfunction to check length and message up on over length, I am editing it to also make sure that it reaches 5 digits so less than 5 digits alerts on exit of input box.  I have an onblurr in it and it's working but if I click the field (make no changes spaces or anything and exit I get an error field 0 error.  Can someone advise as to a better method

```
              $.fn.moRate = function (myLength) {
  fieldVal=$(this).val();

 return this.each(function () {

 $(this).keyup(function() {
   fieldValue=$(this).val();
 if ( !/^[0-9][.]+$/.test($(this).val())  ) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9][.]/g, ''));
 }
  if (fieldValue.length>myLength )
{ 
 this.value=fieldValue.substr(0,myLength);
 var myThis=$(this).attr('id');

moAlert('Number Only Field','You have reached the field length: '+myLength,$(this))
  }
 });
    $(this).blur(function(){

 if ($(this).val()==='')
 { $(this).val(fieldVal)}

if (fieldValue.length!=5){alert('Rate must be 5 digits including decimal')}


 });
 });

 }; 


 };
```

Comment: input has already a min, max, type number built in and has compatibily with all browsers -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Not certain what expected result is ? Is required input five digits including `.` character ?

Comment: yes, forcing numbers with . I know I need to advance the code more later but for now I just want to know why if I click on the field and click out with no entry I get that error.  If I spacebar one space and back up so the field is still empty or blank I do not get an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `required` attribute , `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\d+\.\d+|\.\d+` , `maxlength` attribute set to `6`, `css` `:focus` , `:invalid` pseudo selectors and `title` attribute to display message if input is invalid

```css
input:focus:invalid + [for="input"]:after {
  content: "Rate must be 5 digits including decimal";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input" 
         type="text" 
         pattern="\d+\.\d+|\.\d+" 
         maxlength="6" 
         title="Required input: five digits including a decimal" 
         required /><label for="input"></label><br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```